# Replace a word in an input file

Tags: java, android

I'm doing an attendance system project where I read instructor names, courses, students and students courses and finally student absence.
This is the students file:

```
6
12 Ahmed Suliman 2
ECCE230 0
ECCE356 0
71 Abdulrahim Naser 2
ECCE436 0
ECCE430 0
94 Huda Bassam 3
ECCE356 0
ECCE436 0
ECCE430 0
26 Amna Alzaabi 1
ENGR112 0
52 Mohamed Almansoori 3
ECCE356 0
ECCE430 0
ECCE230 0
80 Noor Alantali 1
ENGR112 0
```

and this is the code I use to read them:

```
int studID[];

    String studFname[], studLname[], studCo[]; int noc, nos;
    Course c[];
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    InputStream input2;

    try {

    int CStuds = 0;
    input2 = assetManager.open("Student info.txt");
    Scanner studscan = new Scanner(input2);
    nos = studscan.nextInt();
    studID = new int[nos];
    studFname = new String[nos];
    studLname = new String[nos];
    for (int e = 0; e < nos; e++)
    {
        studID[e] = studscan.nextInt();
        studFname[e] = studscan.next();
        studLname[e] = studscan.next();
        noc = studscan.nextInt();
        studCo = new String[noc];
        studAbs = new int[noc];
        for (int q = 0; q < noc; q++)
        {
            studCo[q] = studscan.next();
            studAbs[q] = studscan.nextInt();


        }
       for (int h = 0; h < noc; h++){
           if (InsCourse.equals(studCo[h]))
        {
            SelectedStuds[CStuds] = studID[e] + " - "+ studFname[e] + " " + studLname[e];
            studAbs = new int[nos];
            StudentAbsence[CStuds] = studAbs[e];
           //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), SelectedStuds[a], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            CStuds++;
    }
        }
    }
    studscan.close();

    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), SelectedStuds[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    CourseStudents = new String[SelectedStuds.length];
    StudentsAbs = new String[SelectedStuds.length];
    for (int t = 0; t < SelectedStuds.length; t++) {
        CourseStudents[t] = SelectedStuds[t];
        StudentsAbs[t] = StudentAbsence[t] + "%";
    }
   // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), SelectedStuds[0] + SelectedStuds[1], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 ,instructorArray);



} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I didn't paste the full code here but this is enough for the question.
So there is something I read there which is called StudsAbs which is the Absence. In the file its current 0; I'm going to make a button that when pressed should update this value for a specific student. However, I would like to know how to change a specific value for one student in the file and show it up in the program. So how to replace a specific value or word in the input file and update it to show again?[This picture is an example of the attendace. I want the 0% to change when I click save attendance, but how to replace a specific value in the input file?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZplR.jpg)

Comment: Why don't you use a database?

Comment: because my instructor didn't teach me database and its not included in the course I'm taking and they want me to use this method. I need to know how to replace a single value in a txt file.

Comment: Ahhh ok, so I recommend you to store the file elements in a 2d array in groups of ten (if I am not wrong each field have ten elements), after that get the required one from the array and change it.

Comment: isn't there a method or function to replace a value in a txt file?

Comment: I don't think so, this kind of things are usually done by hand, iterating through the text file elements and handling them from code. The task is easy try to do it and you will learn a lot. Basically parse the text file, group the elements, modify them and rewrite the text file, you don't need to change it right in the file, this would be harder.

Comment: And how can I do that? I'm a beginner in Adroid sorry. I want anyway or method to change the value in the file. also, I was never taught to parce a text file. I learned that parcing is changing for example an int to a String. Could you tell me the way to do it please? thank you. I'm looking now how to write to a new file in the assets folder, but I see people saying its impossible. Any help on that?

Comment: This task isn't Android related, it is all about programming. I can't tell you how to do it now, sorry, maybe somebody can, but if you want to learn you should try it by yourself, I told you which steps to follow. To parse a file is just reading it and getting its values.

Comment: Did you post the example file ok? I would expect every student on a new line. And also you messed it with your post text. Dont you see that? Why didnt you repair yourself already?

Comment: Why are there all those empty lines? Cant believe that.